# Identification with multiple fixed effects

Tags: effects, identifiability

I have been thinking about this question for a long time: I wanted to ask that if we have a fixed effect regression (say data on 30 counties over 10 years). Now, say I run a regression

$Y_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{t} + \beta_3 X_{it} + \varepsilon_{it}$

Then my question is that if I have both county $\alpha_{i}$ and year $\beta_{t}$  level fixed effects, then it means I am looking at the effect of the variable $X_{it}$ within a county and a year. But then where is the identification coming from?

What am I comparing here: Because the value of $X_{it}$ will be same for that county in year $t$. Aren't the fixed effects soaking up the variation in $X_{it}$ as well?

Comment: No. $\alpha_i$ is the average value for the country, so characteristics of the country are "soaked up" in this term (maybe proportion college educated). $\beta_t$ is the average value for each year, so the average of common shocks across countries (say spikes in the world price of oil/gasoline) are "soaked up" in this term. However, characteristics of a country that change over time and that change differently across countries are identified. This could be changes in government policy or some disaster that affects a single country, but has a limited geographical scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot. However,I guess i am still trying to understand. Then this doesnot mean as if I am looking within a country and a year to identify. Rather I might be comparing two different countries in diffferent years except that the fixed effects ensure that these are valid counterfactuals with differing values of the variable X?

Comment: Identification could be achieved from both sources of variation depending on your data. For example, if you have firm-level data and multiple firms operating in each province, then the first source of variation could help identify parameters. This level of data is not necessary, however, as long as you have variables changing at the state level over time and differently for each state. One example is the change of some law at the state level that occurs in different time periods for each state. Here, identification is realized by your second example.